# How to read Angular EventEmitter form data using TypeScript?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I am working with Angular 8 and ASP.net Core.

I can parse JSON data from my server using this.

```
let content = new Content(res);
```

I can parse data from a normal form submit using this.

```
var content = form.value as Content;
```

What  I can't do and what I need to do is to be able to parse form data coming back from an EventEmitter. I need to extract an Id out of the object and then pass that into another method. The object looks like JSON to me.

Here is my code. I'm working with ng-Boostrap's Modal service.

```
modalRef.componentInstance.passEntry.subscribe((receivedEntry) =>
```

How do you parse receivedEntry?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `receivedEntry`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Based on @RezaRahmati comment, I changed this @Output() passEntry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); to @Output() passEntry: EventEmitter<Content> = new EventEmitter(); I'm now able to parse it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RezaRahmati comment, I changed @Output from `<any>` to `<Content>`.

```
@Output() passEntry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

@Output() passEntry: EventEmitter<Content> = new EventEmitter();
```

I'm now able to parse it.